# Foreign Key missing when using relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Hi i'm trying to seed my database with fake data.
For that i've 2 models User and Patient.
in User.php

```
public function patients()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);
}
```

in Patient.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My DatabaseSeeder.php

```
$users = factory(User::class, 10)->create();

$users->each(function ($user) {
    $user
        ->patients()
        ->saveMany(factory(Patient::class, 10)
            ->create());
});
```

When i'm trying to seed with relationship I got the error
`general error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

isn't the relationship supposed to fill the foreign key ?

// Edit more information
Patient Migration

```
        if (Schema::hasTable($this->setSchemaTable)) return;
        Schema::create($this->setSchemaTable, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('firstname', 191);
            $table->string('lastname', 191);
            $table->date('birth_date');

            $table->nullableTimestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

PAtientFactory

```
$factory->define(Patient::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'firstname'      => $faker->firstname,
        'lastname'       => $faker->lastname,
        'birth_date'     => $faker->date,
    ];
});
```

user Migration

```
        if (Schema::hasTable($this->setSchemaTable)) return;
        Schema::create($this->setSchemaTable, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname', 191);
            $table->string('lastname', 191);
            $table->string('email', 191)->unique();
            $table->string('password', 191);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->string('lang')->default('en');
            $table->tinyInteger('change_password')->default('1');

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->nullableTimestamps();
        });
```

UserFactory

```
$factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'firstname'         => $faker->firstname,
        'lastname'          => $faker->lastname,
        'email'             => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password'          => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm',   // secret
        'remember_token'    => Str::random(10),
        'lang'              => $faker->randomElement(['fr', 'en']),
        'change_password'   => 0,
    ];
});
```

Comment: show your db configuration.

Comment: `user_id` in database is autoincrement / default value?

Comment: can you show your `user` and  'patient' factory code please?

Comment: @DilipHirapara Message Update with Migration

Comment: @MikeRoss Updated with Factories

Comment: @SimoneRossaini ITs a unsingedInterger with ForeignKey referenced

Comment: what is this `clients` relationship? and the `user` method on `Patient` should have a return

Comment: @lagbox My bad, in mycode its `patients()->saveMany(Factory(...))`
And there is a return, i did rewrite instead of copying

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following, it's working in my project. You can not use relationship to create multiple records the way you are doing. Following will achieve the same.

```
factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function($u) {
    factory(Patient::class, 10)->create(['user_id' => $u->id]);
});
```